# Why is pygame.QUIT being checked when the 'X' button can be clicked and the window would be closed?

Tags: python, pygame

I am learning Python's pygame module so I can make games and I'm fairly new to it. I am watching a tutorial and in the following code, when the for loop is checking for a pygame.QUIT event the run variable is turned to false and pygame.quit() quits pygame.

My question is, **why is the pygame.QUIT being checked when the 'X' button will close the window?**

[image: Youtube tutorial code]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: If you don't check `event.type == pygame.QUIT` and don't set `run = False`, the loop would never terminate and the window would never close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the X button is pressed, an event object is created and added to the event queue. The event objects are retrieved with [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get). The `type` property indicates the type of the event.
If you do not check `event.type == pygame.QUIT` and do not set `run = False`, the loop will never end (endless loop), the application will never terminate and the window will not close.
[`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) deinitializes all pygame modules, which also deinitializes the display module and causes the window to close. The window is also closed when the application exits after your script is finished.

Comment: When pygame.quit() is run then the window will also close because it is a module of pygame, correct?

Comment: @HaseenSiddiqui Yes. I have just verified this and updated the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The "X" button does not automatically force the window to close.  All it does is send a message to the window saying "the user would like to close you now".  It is entirely up to the application to check for that message (in this case, `pygame.QUIT`) and take the appropriate action to close itself.

Comment: So if the code didn't have pygame.quit() the window wouldn't close even if the 'x' button was pressed?

Comment: `pygame.quit()` doesn't close the window. [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) uninitialize all pygame modules

Comment: So it closes pygame, not the entire program?

Comment: The window will close when the program exits, as part of process clean-up, in the same way open files and sockets are closed.  `pygame` would be cleaned up as well, but there is a bug in some IDEs if you don't call `pygame.quit` before the program exits.  https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Computer_Science/Programming_Languages/Book%3A_Making_Games_with_Python_and_Pygame_(Sweigart)/03%3A_Pygame_Basics/3.06%3A_The_QUIT_Event_and_pygame.quit()_Function